# Padding percentage on navigation links

Tags: css, responsive-design, navigation, responsive

I need to make this nav-bar responsive and don`t fall down next button.
How can I do that? I make some variations but nothing changed.
http://student.itdc.ge/k.lolishvili/my_slider/

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using flexbox and FontAwesome icons.

```css
.black {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40%;
}

.red {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.slider .prev:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f053";
  padding-right: .5em;
}

.slider .next:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f054";
  padding-left: .5em;
}

.slider .prev,
.slider .next {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slider .numb {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
    <div class="numb">
      2 of 7
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```